# custom constructor and phpspec

Tags: php, phpspec

I have this class I want to test in phpspec:

```
class Something
{
  protected $property;

  public function __construct($someId)
  {
    $this->property = Model::find($someId);
  }
}
```

Model::find() returns a Model instance.

And I don't want phpspec to use the db etc.
I tried

```
class SomethingSpec
{
  public function let(Model $model)
  {
    $this->property = $model;
  }

  it_is_initializable...
```

But that doesn't work.

Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpSpec encourages you to take a good care of how code is designed. Many things are not possible to prevent you from hurting yourself. [This is by design](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2014/09/11/my-top-ten-favourite-phpspec-limitations/). If you want to do things like you presented in the question, use another tool (phpunit for example).

Accessing `Model::find($someId)` from a constructor is not a good design and it's not testable (see the [Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and other [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))).

You should inject your dependency from the outside context. Either inject a `Model` instance or a result of `Model::find()` call:

```php
class Something
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

Start with a spec first, before you write the code. It will make your life easier.

Comment: I was suspecting that. Thanks for confirming!